# How can I accomplish multiple threads to join multiple times into a process? (pthread_mutex_lock)

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I want to write a program, what counts to 100. I want to accomplish this with 10 threads, using pthread lock. When the program steps into a thread it generates a number between 0-2, this value will be added to it's index of array and also to the global variable sum. When the sum value reaches 100, every thread should print it's own value of array (the amount of the entire array should be equal with the sum variable).

My problem is the following: Always the first thread locks the mutex variable, but I want to distribute the tasks between all threads (arr[1] = 100, every other = 0, but I want for example arr[1] = 14, arr[2] = 8, etc. up to 100). Where am I wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
int arr[10];
int sum = 0;

void *add (void* input) {

    int *id = (int*) input, x, s;
    int ind = *id;

    while (sum < 100) {
        while (1) {
            if (pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutex) != EBUSY)
                break;
        }

        if (sum < 100) {
            x = rand() % 3;
            arr[ind] = arr[ind] + x;
            sum += x;
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        sleep(0.1);
    }

    printf("The %d. thread got %d points!\n", ind, arr[ind]);
    return NULL;
}

int main (void) {

    int i;
    pthread_t threads[10];
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, add, &i)){
            perror("pthread_create");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (pthread_join (threads[i], NULL)){
            perror("pthread_join");
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
The 1. thread got 100 points!
The 2. thread got 0 points!
The 3. thread got 0 points!
The 4. thread got 0 points!
The 5. thread got 0 points!
The 6. thread got 0 points!
The 7. thread got 0 points!
The 8. thread got 0 points!
The 9. thread got 0 points!
The 0. thread got 0 points!
```

Comment: I think the problem may be that `sleep()` takes an `int`, so `0.1` gets converted to `0`.  So the `sleep()` doesn't do anything, and the first thread finishes before the next gets a chance to do anything.

Comment: In `main`, you can just pass `(void *) i` as the last argument and, in `add`, do `int id = (int) input`. Also, instead of `pthread_mutex_trylock` in a loop, just do `pthread_mutex_lock` without a loop. The trylock version will burn huge amounts of CPU needlessly. The lock version will give up the CPU until the lock has been released.

Comment: Use _[`usleep()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/usleep.3.html)_ to sleep for intervals smaller than one second on any unix-like (e.g., Linux) operating system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems in your code, with varying degrees of relevance to the specific issue you asked about.  Before we go further, one output *I* get from running your code as written may be illustrative:

> ```
> The 2. thread got 100 points!
> The 8. thread got 0 points!
> The 9. thread got 0 points!
> The 5. thread got 0 points!
> The 5. thread got 0 points!
> The 6. thread got 0 points!
> The 7. thread got 0 points!
> The 2. thread got 100 points!
> The 4. thread got 0 points!
> The 1. thread got 0 points!
> ```

Note that some threads got the same counter index.  This can happen because you have a data race between the main thread and each child thread: the main thread passes a pointer to its local variable `i`, and then proceeds to modify the value of that variable.  Meanwhile the child thread reads the value of the variable via the pointer.  These actions are not synchronized, so the behavior is undefined.

This particular problem has several solutions.  The simplest is probably to *cast* `i` to `void *` and pass the result (by value).  This is in fact pretty common where you just want to pass an integer:

```
        if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, add, (void *)i)) {
            // ...
```

Of course, the thread function needs to convert it back:

```
void *add (void* input) {
    int /*no need for 'id' */ x, s;
    int ind = (int) input;
    // ...
```

Next, observe that you have *another* data race among all your child threads where you read the value of `sum` in the condition of the `while` loop.  That one does not seem to be biting you at the moment, but it could do at any time.  Since the threads, as a group, both read and modify `sum`, you must ensure that all such accesses are synchronized -- for example, by performing them only while holding the mutex locked.

Skipping a bit (we'll come back), you have a problem with your `sleep()` call.  That function's parameter is of type `int`, so your actual argument, the `double` 0.1, is converted to `int`, yielding 0.  The compiler might optimize that out altogether, and if it doesn't, then it might effectively be a no-op.  **Even more importantly**, however.  `sleep()` is simply the wrong tool for this job, or for pretty much any job related to inter-thread synchronization and timing.

Recognizing now that there is no sleeping, you should see that your outer `while` loop is quite tight, in that a thread that has just unlocked the mutex will immediately try to lock it again.  It is quite common for such a re-locking attempt to succeed on the first try, because default mutex behavior makes no promises about thread scheduling fairness.

Additionally, you gain no particular benefit from the peculiar busy loop around `pthread_mutex_trylock()`.  Just use `pthread_mutex_lock()` if otherwise all you're going to do when the mutex is busy is re-try.  This will save you CPU time and does not have appreciably different semantics.

Overall, though, you have a strategy problem.  Mutexes do not generally provide any guarantees around fair scheduling.  Usually for a tight multithread interaction such as this one, you need to perform some kind of scheduling management manually, and that typically benefits greatly from adding a condition variable to the mix.

It looks like you don't want to force the threads to take turns, but perhaps it would be sufficient to ensure that the thread that just ran does not immediately get selected again.  In that case, you could add a shared variable that records the index of the thread that just ran, and use that to prevent it from being selected again as the next thread.  Schematically, the thread function might then look something like this

- loop indefinitely:

  - lock the mutex
  - loop indefinitely:

    - compare the last thread index to my index
    - if it is different, break from the (inner) loop
    - else wait on the condition variable
  - set my index as the last thread index
  - (still holding the mutex locked) broadcast to or signal the CV
  - if `sum` is less than 100

    - update `sum`
    - unlock the mutex
  - otherwise (`sum` is >= 100)

    - unlock the mutex
    - break from the (outer) loop

Answer (score 0):

I found two problems.

When I tried this on Windows with MSys2 my output was

```
The 1. thread got 101 points!
The 1. thread got 101 points!
The 2. thread got 0 points!
The 3. thread got 0 points!
The 5. thread got 0 points!
The 6. thread got 0 points!
The 6. thread got 0 points!
The 8. thread got 0 points!
The 9. thread got 0 points!
The 0. thread got 0 points!
```

You pass the address of your loop counter `i` to the threads. This variable is not constant, that's why the threads may read a value that has already changed. To fix thisI created an array `int ids[10]` and passed every thread its own ID array element.

Function `sleep` uses an `unsigned int` argument, so you effectively call `sleep(0)`. With `sleep(1)` the program runs slower but works as expected. You can use `usleep` if you want to sleep for fractions of a second.

Modified program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
int arr[10];
int sum = 0;

void *add (void* input){

    int *id = (int*) input, x, s;
    int ind = *id;
    while (sum < 100){
        while (1){
            if (pthread_mutex_trylock(&mutex) != EBUSY)
                break;
        }
        if (sum < 100){
            x = rand() % 3;
            arr[ind] = arr[ind] + x;
            sum += x;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        usleep(100000);
    }
    printf("The %d. thread got %d points!\n", ind, arr[ind]);
    return NULL;
}

int main (void){

    int i;
    pthread_t threads[10];
    int ids[10];
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        ids[i] = i;
        if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, add, &ids[i])){
            perror("pthread_create");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if (pthread_join (threads[i], NULL)){
            perror("pthread_join");
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you helped more than you think :)